# Join multiple table on SQL, and Order by

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'm working on wordpress and I wanna display a POST with them different taxonomy.

I have some trouble to make a query, and I'm working on it for 2 days now..

My Query :

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_content, wp_posts.post_type,
wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy, wp_terms.name
FROM wp_term_relationships, wp_term_taxonomy, wp_terms, wp_posts
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'dimsum'
AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = wp_terms.term_id
AND wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.ID
```

This is what the console display : 
http://tinyurl.com/bnw2dot

But I wanna display on my wordpress Theme something like that :

**That need to be Ordered by Reference**

Dimsum :

N1 -- 蟹皇烧买  -- test -- test (4) --  5.00

N10 -- 晶莹鲜虾饺  --  Har Kau -- Steamed Prawn Dumpling (4) -- 5.00

N11 -- 蟹皇烧买  -- Siu Mai -- Steamed Prawn And Pork Dumpling (4) --5.00

If someone can help me please, I'm desperate

Comment: I can't understand how it should be

Comment: what do you don't understand ? what i wanna display ?

Comment: So what's your actual problem. Have you managed to get the query working?  Or you just want to output the query as a table on the page?

Comment: basically the query is working, but take a look on my link. That's what she display.
But i wanna display something like :
[reference][chinesename][content][additonalinformation][price]
Ordered by reference

Answer (score 0):

Add `ORDER BY` and interesting for order field.

```
    SELECT wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_content, wp_posts.post_type,
    wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy, wp_terms.name
    FROM wp_term_relationships, wp_term_taxonomy, wp_terms, wp_posts
    WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'dimsum'
    AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
    AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = wp_terms.term_id
    AND wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.ID 
    ORDER BY wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy DESC //(OR ASC)
```

Comment: That's what the consol display now : http://tinyurl.com/blrh2vp

But how can I get my needed result ? in PHP ?

In order to get on the same line : 

[reference][chinesename][content][additonalinformation][price] 

Ordered by reference

Comment: You want another order of columns in your phpmyadmin?

Comment: No I don't, I think that I have been clear sorry.
I just wanna display on my wordpress theme what I wrote before.
[reference][chinesename][content][additonalinformation][price] Ordered by reference
Using mysql and php.
You should take a look on my link in order to see what the query display.

Comment: I dont see reference field name sorry

Comment: There is no reference field, that's the probleme. Reference is include in taxonomy field

Comment: @socrateisabot If you want to show `reference` records only, add `AND wp_term_taxonomy = 'reference'` to WHERE clause. If not, please try to be more clear as "ordered by reference" is not sufficient.